# Why do I need the x permission to cd into a directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

`ls -la` prints the following:

```
drwxrwxrw- 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 12 11:04 files
```

My username does not belong to **www-data**. When trying to `cd` into *files* I get a "`permission denied`" though the "`read`" permission for others is set.

Why do I need the "**execute**" permission?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The meaning of execute permission for a directory is the ability to look up file names inside that directory.

Without execute permission on the directory, you **can't stat, open, rename, delete, or descend into subdirectories inside that directory**.

The only thing you can do is see the list of which filenames exist, and then only if you have read permission (and read but not execute is a strange set of permissions to have for a directory).

If you are not owner of the given directory, become a owner by using,

```
sudo chown username /path/to/directory
```

**Or better way is to add user to a group,**

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

for getting execute permission use,

```
sudo chmod a+x /path/to/dir
```

Comment: ... or add your user to the group.

Comment: Changing the owner of files or folders belonging to "www-data" is probably not a good idea. Your webserver will not be able to read the files any more.

Comment: Have to mention though that merely adding the user to the group won't change permissions of currently running processes. You should either login as yourself again in terminal (i.e. `su $(whoami)`) to have these rights for this terminal session, or logout of the whole system and re-login to have this take effect for all your apps.

Comment: Actually the meaning of execute permission is the ability to *traverse* the directory. For instance, even if you have execute (and read) permission on a directory you are still not allowed to look up file names in it if a *higher* directory does not grant you execute permission.

Comment: "*The meaning of execute permission for a directory is the ability to look up file names inside that directory.*", no, that's what the read permission is for. The execute permission on a directory is for the ability to go into it (or use anything in it).

Comment: "(and read but not execute is a strange set of permissions to have for a directory)."

No, it isn't. If there are not supposed to be executables in a folder setting rw but not x makes perfect sense. This restriction makes no sense.