# Weird permissions after sudo chmod

Tags: 20.10, chmod

On Ubuntu 20.10.  When I run something like:

sudo chmod -R +766 /etc/apache2

I end up with permissions that do not allow my user (in group "other") to access the files in /etc/apache2.  When I look at the permissions in nautilus, they say something something "no access".

How do I fix this???

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Why do I need the x permission to cd into a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660502/why-do-i-need-the-x-permission-to-cd-into-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux (and other POSIX-like operating systems), the execute bit has a special meaning for directories:  it means that the given user or group can access the inodes of the files inside the directory.  So chmod g+r on a directory means that group members can list the files, but they can't know anything about them, and chmod g+rx is needed to actually read the files inside.

You probably should be doing chmod -R +755, not 766.

Comment: Well there you go.  Thank you!