# Permission denied with 0660 when using cd

Tags: permissions

I have a directory:

```
drw-rw---- 2 myuser somegroup 4096 Jul 26 20:04 share
```

Which I also made myself (myuser) the owner of. However if I try to move into this directory with `cd` I get:

```
-bash: cd: share: Permission denied
```

I'm not a linux guru but shouldn't I have access with these permissions? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [Why do I need the x permission to cd into a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660502/why-do-i-need-the-x-permission-to-cd-into-a-directory)

Comment: Run the command `chmod +x share`

Answer (score 0):

As comments say, apparently I'm really a noob and to enter a directory and list files one need execute privs on said directory.